# Execute arbitrary procedural code in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In T-SQL, I can declare variables and otherwise write any procedural code I wish inside or outside of a stored procedure. In PostgreSQL, I can say something like…

```
DO $$
DECLARE foo INT DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
  -- Blah blah
END;
$$;
```

And this executes some arbitrary procedural code. Is there anything like this in MySQL or do I have to create a "throwaway" stored procedure? (That's not the end of the world for my use case, but I'm curious if there's a better way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have that feature to execute procedural sentences outsite of body of stored procedure... so the answer is yes, you must create a regular stored procedure to run your code.

Comment: Or use a client such as PHP/Java/etc., or the MySQL commandline tool, for such programming.